# How to make the snake bodyParts follow same places and directions as the player on a curved surface?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody, snake

I try to make a game like the classic snake game but on a round ground (Earth). On a plane, the script works well, but when i moved it on a sphere, the bodyparts (prefabs), are not working good as you can see in the picture ( they are going right/left, but they do not sit on the spehre and i tried already to use sphere collider, box collider, rigidbody) and i dont know really how to make it so that they will follow 100% correctly the player. Thanks for help! :/ . Here i put the script for the Player and bodyparts:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

protected Joystick joystick;
public float speed;
[SerializeField] private float turnFactor;
[SerializeField] private Transform planet;
public List<Transform> bodyParts = new List<Transform>();
public float minDistance = 0.25f;
public int beginSize;
public float rotationSpeed = 50;
public float timeFromLastRetry;
public GameObject bodyprefabs;
public Text currentScore;
public Text scoreText;
public GameObject deadScreen;
private float dis;
private Transform curBodyPart;
private Transform PrevBodyPart;

public bool isAlive;
 void Start()
{
 joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
 speed = 3f;
 StartLevel();
}
public void StartLevel()
{
 timeFromLastRetry = Time.deltaTime;
 //deadScreen.SetActive(false);
 for (int i = bodyParts.Count -1; i > beginSize; i++)
 {
     Destroy(bodyParts[i].gameObject);
     bodyParts.Remove(bodyParts[i]);
 }
 bodyParts[0].position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
 for (int i = 0; i < beginSize - 1; i++)
 {
     AddBodyPart();
 }
 bodyParts[0].position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
 bodyParts[0].rotation = Quaternion.identity;
 currentScore.gameObject.SetActive(true);
 currentScore.text = "Score: 0";
 isAlive = true;
}
void Update()
{
 if (isAlive)
       Move();
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
     AddBodyPart();
 //RotateAroundPlanet();
 var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
 //rb.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * 100f, rb.velocity.y, joystick.Vertical * 100f);
}
public void Move()
{
 float curspeed = speed;
 //if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
 //    curspeed *= 2;
 bodyParts[0].Translate(bodyParts[0].forward * curspeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime, Space.World);
 if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
     bodyParts[0].Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
 for (int i = 1; i < bodyParts.Count; i++)
 {
     curBodyPart = bodyParts[i];
     PrevBodyPart = bodyParts[i - 1];
     dis = Vector3.Distance(PrevBodyPart.position, curBodyPart.position);
     Vector3 newpos = PrevBodyPart.position;
     newpos.y = bodyParts[0].position.y;
     float T = Time.deltaTime * dis / minDistance * curspeed;
     if (T > 0.5f)
         T = 0.5f;
     curBodyPart.position = Vector3.Slerp(curBodyPart.position, newpos, T);
     curBodyPart.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(curBodyPart.rotation, PrevBodyPart.rotation, T);
 }
}
public void AddBodyPart()
{
 Transform newpart = (Instantiate(bodyprefabs, bodyParts[bodyParts.Count - 1].position, 
 bodyParts[bodyParts.Count - 1].rotation) as GameObject).transform;
 newpart.SetParent(transform);
 bodyParts.Add(newpart);
 currentScore.text = "Score: " + (bodyParts.Count - beginSize).ToString();
}
public void Die()
{
 isAlive = false;
 scoreText.text = "Your score was: " + (bodyParts.Count - beginSize).ToString();
 currentScore.gameObject.SetActive(false);
 deadScreen.SetActive(true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably remove the line `newpos.y = bodyParts[0].position.y;`. That doesn't make sense for the type of 3D movement you're trying to achieve.

Comment: OMG, that was the only thing I had to do to make it work! Thanks a lot! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the planet and body parts are all spheres, you don't even need to use colliders or physics. Keep in mind that by definition, every single point on the surface of a perfect sphere is exactly the same distance from the center of the sphere (that distance being the sphere's radius). Using this fact and `Vector3.MoveTowards()`, we can easily implement logic to move along a sphere's surface.

```
[SerializeField] private Transform sphere; //set in Inspector
float bodyPartSpacing = 1; //change to suit the size of your body parts
float sphereRadius = 10; //change to suit the size of your sphere
void Update() {
    //other code goes here
    //[...]

    //align the snake's head to the surface of the sphere
    SetDistance(bodyParts[0], sphere, sphereRadius + bodyPartSpacing / 2f);
    //align body parts
    for (int i = 1; i < bodyParts.Count; i++) {
        curBodyPart = bodyParts[i];
        prevBodyPart = bodyParts[i - 1];
        //align to previous body part
        SetDistance(curBodyPart, prevBodyPart, bodyPartSpacing);
        //align to surface of sphere
        SetDistance(curBodyPart, sphere, sphereRadius);

        //update rotation; simply look at the previous body part
        //while maintaining "up" as directly-away-from-the-sphere
        Vector3 up = curBodyPart.position - sphere.position;
        curBodyPart.LookAt(prevBodyPart.positiion, up);
    }
}

//Move 'a' so that it is 'desiredDistance' units from 'b'
private void SetDistance(Transform a, Transform b, float desiredDistance) {
     float distance = Vector3.Distance(a.position, b.position);
     float excess = distance - desiredDistance;
     a.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(a.position, b.position, excess);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One very simple way to do this would be to only move the front ball and attach each ball to the next ball with a joint component. Here is a useful video describing all the joint components in unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MElbAwhMvTc.

Comment: I don't think it would work for the same reason that a trailer does not follow the exact same path as the car pulling it: the pulled objects held with joints will take the shortest path available and "flatten" the curves made by the head.

Comment: It's not working well. I tough that maybe in my code i need to modify something if you can  help m. I'm new and a bit noob :/